# Configuring only one Internet Explorer zone (IntranetZone) thru GPO without affecting other zones?

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer

I need to deploy some trusted intranet sites into `Intranet Zone` in `Internet Explorer`. It works fine when using GPO at:

> Setting Path: Computer
>   Configuration/Administrative
>   Templates/Windows Components/Internet
>   Explorer/Internet Control
>   Panel/Security
>
> Page Supported On: At
>   least Internet Explorer 6.0 in Windows
>   XP Service Pack 2 or Windows Server
>   2003 Service Pack 1

Problem is this settings also affect other zones making it impossible for people in company to add sites to other zones themselves.

Is there a way to fix this so that `Intranet Zone` is deployed thru GPO and rest of settings stay in gesture of users?

Comment: could you provide the details how to apply this because the site provided by @smassey is down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option to deploy websites to a zone using Group Policy Preferences is to deploy them as a Registry Preference.  [This site](http://simultaneouspancakes.com/Lessons/2011/09/02/adding-urls-to-internet-explorer-security-zones-with-group-policy-preferences/) outlines how to set that up.

I use this method to deploy Trusted Sites to a virtual desktop environment.

Comment: could you provide the details in here again because the site is down?

Answer (score 2):

Turn off the Zone to Assignment list, you still have it enabled.  I would disable it so turns off that forced feature (if you just go unconfigured, everyone that has it enabled will stay enabled I believe) and then use the preferences.  The policy (if still in effect which it sounds like it is) is overriding the preferences.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using Group Policy Preferences.  This is if you have a 2008 R2 DC and your environment has been prepped for it.  GP preferences allow you to push settings (in your case User IE zone settings), and still allow users to modify them.  Also note that you would need the [Client Side Extensions](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3628) installed on any non-Windows 7 machines for this to work.

Once you have your environment ready, from the 2008 R2 DC, go into the GPMC and create a new GPO.  Edit the GPO and you will see new sections in both the Computer and User configurations called "Preferences".  Expand the User preferences to see "Internet Settings".  Right click "Internet Settings" and create a new Preference item.  Modify this item as you would a local IE settings GUI window.  If you want these settings to only be applied once and then allow the user to add/ remove/ etc:  When modifying the preference item, go to the "common" tab and check the "apply once..." box.

Comment: I do have 2008 R2 DC so I'll try it.

Comment: Does it allow for us to keep deploying the site list and if user changes the site list (removes the ones applied by gpo) it will upload it back without affecting other user entries?

Comment: The other problem is that `sites` are disabled and cannot be modified.

Comment: If you don't use the "apply once..." check box, yes, entries on the list will be re-applied once the GPO refreshes.

Comment: What about the last problem (that sites are disabled).

Comment: Do you mean Trusted / Restricted Sites?

Comment: I mean Trusted / Restricted Sites / Intranet sites. Just the `sites` button is disabled. It seems I can change many settings just not add the chosen ones to the list.